# Array increment positioning with respect to indexer in C - array[i]++ vs array[i++]

Tags: c, arrays

What is the difference between `array[i]++` (increment outside brackets) and `array[i++]` (increment inside brackets), where the array is an int `array[10]`?

Answer (score 32, accepted):

```
int a[] = {1, 2, 3, 4, 5};
int i = 1; // Second index number of the array a[]
a[i]++;
printf("%d %d\n", i, a[i]);
a[i++];
printf("%d %d\n", i, a[i]);
```

Output

```
1 3
2 3
```

`a[i]++` increments the element at index `i`, it doesn't increment `i`. And `a[i++]` increments `i`, not the element at index `i`.

Comment: What's missing from this answer is what `a[i]++` and `a[i++]` evaluate to.

Comment: It is a little bit confusing because the array *values* are in about the same range as the array *indexes*. Can you offset the values (say, by 60), so there isn't any overlap between indexes and values?

Comment: The example output is misleading, since the access of `a[i++]` in the second statement actually returns the value at index `1`, which has been inceremented to `3` before. Be aware that `x = a[i++];` is equivalent to the statement sequence `x = a[i]; i++;` So i is used as index *before* it is incremented.

Answer (score 25):

- `array[i]++` increments the value of `array[i]`. The expression evaluates to `array[i]` before it has been incremented.
- `array[i++]` increments the value of `i`. The expression evaluates to `array[i]`, before `i` has been incremented.

An illustration.

Suppose that `array` contains three integers, 0, 1, 2, and that `i` is equal to 1.

- `array[i]++` changes `array[1]` to 2, evaluates to 1 and leaves `i` equal to 1.
- `array[i++]` does not modify `array`, evaluates to 1 and changes `i` to 2.

A suffix operators, which you are using here, evaluates to the value of the expression before it is incremented.

Answer (score 5):

`array[i]++` means `( *(array+i) )++`. --> Increments the Value.

`array[i++]` means `*( array + (i++) )`. --> Increments the Index.

Answer (score 2):

Here the `Array[i]++` increments the value of the element `array[i]`,
but `array[i++]` increments the `i` value which effects or changes the indication of the array element (i.e. it indicates the next element of an array after `array[i]`).

Answer (score 1):

Let's say we have this example, `array[i++] = x[m++]`. This means that first set `array[i] = x[m]` then increase the indexes like `i + 1`, `m + 1`.

Answer (score 0):

Here `array[i++]` increments the index number.
On the contrary, `array[i]++` increments the data value of `i` index.

Code Snippet:

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

int main() 
{
    int array[] = {5, 2, 9, 7, 15};

    int i = 0;

    array[i]++;
    printf("%d %d\n", i, array[i]);

    array[i]++;
    printf("%d %d\n", i, array[i]);

    array[i++];
    printf("%d %d\n", i, array[i]);

    array[i++];
    printf("%d %d\n", i, array[i]);

    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score -1):

```
#include<iostream>
using namespace std;
int main()
{
    int arr[]={1,2,37,40,5,7};
    int i = 3;
    arr[i]++;
    cout<<i<<" "<<arr[i]<<endl;
    arr[i++];
    cout<<i<<" "<<arr[i]<<endl;
    return 0;
}
```

Output:

```
3 41
4 5
```

In this example `i = 3`, so `arr[3] = 40`. It then increases the value from 40 to 41 .So `arr[i]++` increments the value of this particular index and `a[i++]` first increments the **index** and then gives the value for this index.

Comment: a[i++] first gives the value and then increments i