# Order of evaluation >> and [++]

Tags: c++, operator-precedence

I have a question about the precedence in an operation in C++. I have search for precedence in http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/operator_precedence and I read this question that is more or less the same [array increment difference in C](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7595247/array-increment-difference-in-c)

I didn't get any clear conclusion. If I do

```
var >> array[n++];
```

Operator >> is for stream that is reading chars. ¿Where it is stored what I read? In n or in n+1?

Thank you

Comment: Order of evaluation and precedence are completely different concepts, neither one relevant to your question.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

This isn't really to do with precedence, it's to do with the semantics of post-increment.

```
var >> array[n++];
```

`n++` will increment `n` and evaluate to the original value of `n`. As such, it's equivalent to writing:

```
var >> array[n];
++n;
```

So the value will be read into `array[n]`.

Comment: Or ...  *the value will be read into **array[n-1]** if you take n to be the after-the-statement value*

Answer (score 4):

It is stored in n. n++ increments the counter and returns the old value. ++n increments the counter and returns the new value.

Also see [What is the difference between ++i and i++?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24853/what-is-the-difference-between-i-and-i)

Comment: And you should note that this isn't  an operator precedence issue. It is an order of evaluation issue.